# Выдать привилегию на определенные колонки в таблице

Tags: postgresql, права

Речь идет о СУБД PostgreSQL

Суть задачи в том, чтобы выдать привилегию на определенные колонки. Имеет таблицу, содержащую примерно 20 колонок. Необходимо разрешить редактирование 19 из 20. Или запретить редактирование 1 колонки из 20. как вам будет угодно. Другая постановка вопроса, но суть та же.

Как мы это делаем? Для начала запрещаем полностью редактировать таблицу. Затем выдаем персональную привилегию на каждую колонку.

Это тот способ, до которого додумался я. Но это очень муторно. быть может можно как то по другому?

Comment: Вроде как нельзя - нет у Postgres прав типа запрет.

Comment: быть может можно как то указать на все колонки, исключая определенные?

Comment: В этом случае привилегия повиснет в воздухе при переименовании или удалении колонки, которую попытались исключить, что приведет к неопределенному поведению. Нет, только через перечисление. Хотя можно попробовать оптимизировать, достав список колонок в таблице через какой-нибудь (MSSQL вроде умеет через запрос к sys.tables) SELECT с исключением в явном виде, а потом на каждую дать GRANT.

Comment: @Vesper: *нет у Postgres прав типа запрет* — [есть](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-revoke.html). можно столбцы перечислить примерно так: `revoke update (столбец1, столбец2, столбец3) on таблица from у-кого`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ну это не право запрет, это "отобрать право", но если сработает при наличии прав только на всю таблицу целиком - круто.

Comment: @Vesper, ну, филологические споры (запрет vs отзыв) — не по моей части. вначале прав нет. потом даются на update таблицы, потом отзываются на update столбцов.

Comment: Чтобы отобрать привилегию на столбцы, ее, я так понимаю, сначала нужно выдать? Т.е. мне надо выдать доступ к каждому столбцу а потом забрать у некоторых. Я сейчас попробовал выдать доступ на всю таблицу, а потому отобрать у некоторых колонок - не сработало. А как выдать доступ на все колонки я не знаю

Answer (score 1):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-revoke.html
Вам надо:

1. Отобрать у public все права на эту таблицу
2. Убедиться, что пользователь не входит в привилегированные группы
3. Отобрать все права на все столбцы в таблице
4. Выдать нужные права.

Пример:

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbl_test (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  name TEXT DEFAULT ''::text NOT NULL,
  data TEXT DEFAULT ''::text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tbl_test_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

И пользователь `test`.
Нам надо, чтобы он имел право просматривать всю таблицу, но не мог редактировать поле `name`,
но мог редактировать остальные поля:

```
REVOKE ALL ON public.tbl_test FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON public.tbl_test FROM test; 
GRANT SELECT  ON public.tbl_test TO test;
GRANT  INSERT (id,data) , UPDATE (id,data)  ON public.tbl_test TO test;
```

Comment: вопрос не в том как выдать права. Вопрос в том как запретить редактировать определенные колонки.

Comment: Приведите скрипт создания таблицы, парочку пользователей, укажите кому запретить редактировать какие колонки.